# CRM 2013: Set Business Process default by User

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In our organization we have to implement different Business Process Flows for the different sales people on the Opportunity.  I have created the different Business Processes.  I am aware that I can switch the Business Processes on the form.

My question then: is it possible to set a different default Business Process for different users?  For example: some sales people specialize mostly in quoting customers for training while other sell products.  Hence there is a different Business Process for Goods than for Services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. It works similar as with forms, you can assign Business Process Flow to appropriate roles. See MSDN ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531164.aspx#BKMK_MultipleBPF)) for little bit more details.

[Here](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/12/31/control-access-to-business-processes-security-role/) you can find description with visualization.

Comment: I have looked at the roles.  My issue is that when using roles, the sales people cannot access other Business Process Flows.  I want to change the default Business Process for each sales person, but all sales people should still be able to access all Business Process Flows.

Comment: Thus wont work as far as i know. You might want to try some custom code in jscript, or plugins when record is created. There are two fields on record that store BPF information: _processid_ and _stageid_